# PuTTY serial configuration from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, putty

I'm trying to automate PuTTY using batch file. I am able to run serial session but I need to set up two additional things:

- Terminal -> Local echo: Force on;
- Terminal -> Local line editing: Force on

I have no idea what command would allow me to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no command-line switch for that, if that's what you ask for.

All you can do is to configure a "saved session" and open that from your batch file.

You can, of course, create a temporary "saved session" from the batch file.

These questions show how:

- [PuTTY psftp command line with proxy authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37507791/850848)
- [Command line option for PuTTY (Windows) to set action of mouse buttons to xterm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28934869/850848)
- [Set negotiation mode on Plink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44656971/850848)
- [Is it possible to load PuTTY connection information (session) from file?](https://superuser.com/q/963563/213663)

Comment: Thanks for an answer Martin.
is there a way to automate saved session configuration, where I set the echo and line editing by command and then open that session?

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer shows, isn't it? Do want to know what specific registry entries to set? Just save the settings in PuTTY GUI and check what changes in registry.

Comment: got it. thanks
I have one more issue: putty.exe -load asic -m commands.txt
it doesn't input content of commands.txt to putty unfortunately. I saw a different topic on that but proposed solutions don't work either

Comment: And indeed the `-m` does not work with serial connection, only with SSH. For solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/30826002/850848

Comment: Thanks again Marin. It seems kinda working. How would I insert more than one command (commands differ in length and should be sent by pressing ENTER)

Comment: Put each command on a separate line in the input file - If you have additional question, post it separately. This is Q&A site, not a chat.